# How to make prediction (model inference) in torchtext Machine Translation Task in python?

Tags: python, pytorch, machine-translation, torchtext

I finished [this](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/torchtext_translation_tutorial.html) pytorch tutorial and i was able to understand everything except making prediction using the model since the tutorial did not implement that I have to figure out myself. Here is what I've tried so far, It have been a week trying this but I'm failing to find the solution:

1. I created the function `translate_sentence` which takes the following args:

```
Args:
    src_field -> contains a key and value of each word for example {"the": 7, ...} for french
    trg_field -> for the target language which is english
    sentence -> sentence can be either a row sentence or the tokenized one
```

```py
def translate_sentence(sentence, src_field, trg_field, model, device, max_len = 50):
    model.eval()
    if isinstance(sentence, str):
        tokens = [token.lower() for token in fr_tokenizer(sentence)]
    else:
        tokens = [token.lower() for token in sentence]

    tokens = ["<sos>"] + tokens + ["<eos>"]
    src_indexes = [src_field.stoi[token] for token in tokens]

    src_tensor = torch.LongTensor(src_indexes).unsqueeze(1).to(device)

    with torch.no_grad():
      encoder_outputs, hidden = model.encoder(src_tensor)
    trg_indexes = [trg_field.stoi["<sos>"]]
    for i in range(max_len):
      trg_tensor = torch.LongTensor([trg_indexes[-1]]).to(device)
      with torch.no_grad():
        output, hidden = model.decoder(trg_tensor, hidden, encoder_outputs)
      pred_token = output.argmax(1).item()
      trg_indexes.append(pred_token)
      if pred_token == trg_field.stoi['<eos>']:
        break

    trg_tokens = [trg_field.itos[i] for i in trg_indexes]
    return trg_tokens
translate_sentence("va", fr_vocab, en_vocab, model, device, max_len = 50)
```

**When i run this code cell this is what i get which i can see that it is totally predicting wrongly...**

Output:

```
['<sos>', '<unk>', 'has', 'a', 'talented', '.', '\n', '<eos>']
```

**I've looked for solution and i found [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59549980/language-translation-using-torchtext-pytorch) which i totally don't understand.**

Comment: The inference code looks good. The problem is more likely in training the model. It can be undertrained or overfitted, there can be a vocabulary mismatch between the train and test data... plenty of things might have gone wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your response at this point in time, may you try to fix that bug for me if you can, i will appreciate that more and forever